# Homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

I want to describe all homomorphisms between the ring of rational $\Bbb{Q}(x)$ functions and the ring of complex numbers $\Bbb{C}$.

my idea: Let $\phi:\Bbb{Q}(x)\longrightarrow\Bbb{C}$ be a homomorphism such that $\phi(1)=1$. Then it is easy to show that $\phi|_{\Bbb{Q}}=\rm id_{\Bbb{Q}}$. Then for any $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\in\Bbb{Q}(x)$, we have $\phi(p(x)/q(x))=\frac{p(\phi(x))}{q(\phi(x))}$. Then $\phi$ is determined by the image og $x$. therefore $x$ must go to some transcendental number in $\Bbb{C}$, otherwise $q(\phi(x))$ maybe $0$. Therefore there exists an unique homomorphism $\phi_{\alpha}$ for any transcendental number $\alpha\in\Bbb{C}$. Am I right about this? Is this description perfect?

Comment: yes, this is correct. to be precise, you are using the universal property of the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and then the universal property of its field of fractions, which is $\mathbb{Q}(x)$

Comment: Plus the trivial homomorphism $\phi(p)=0$, if your definition of ring homomorphism allows it.

Comment: No, my ring homomorphism is defined with the condition $\phi(1)=1$ to avoid the trivial one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your description is correct, and moreover it uses no special features of $\mathbb{C}$: this is a description of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ to any field, which exhibits the universal property of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ in the category of fields, namely, it is the free field on a transcendental element.